# How to calculate distance of clouds in image

Tags: image-processing, physics

I have a question about image processing - say I have picture from a satellite, that has a lot of clouds in it (like the image below) can I calculate the distance between them and the camera ? or between them and the ground ?
[image]

Comment: You can't......

Comment: You need at least two images taken from different locations to estimate depth information.

Comment: If there was an airliner visible above the clouds you could maybe deduce they were below 40,000 feet. If you recognised the cloud type and knew the altitudes such clouds formed at, you could estimate their altitude. But there is no way to calculate distance from a single image from a single location like this.